# How to accept touches only on some area of the view in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have this view hierarchy:

```
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View ... />
    <View style={{
      position: "absolute", 
      bottom: 0, 
      right: 0, 
      width: Dimensions.get("screen").width, 
      height: Dimensions.get("screen").height,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0)'
    }}
      pointerEvents='none'
    >
      <WebView
        pointerEvents='none'
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0)' }}
        source={require("source/assets/tawkto.html")}
      />
    </View>
  </View >
```

My html consists of 1 widget element and a transparent background. The WebView which displays the html is located on top of every view in my hierarchy. 
So my question is **is it possible to accept touches only on the widget area (e. g. the fixed rect area that i know)**. By using `pointerEvents` I achieved that views does not accept touches at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<View pointerEvents={'none'} />` on those views that you want touch to be disabled

Comment: The problem is with WebView which renders an html. The elements are not react components so the only solution i see is to disable/allow touches on some specific points in WebView. On iOS it’s not a difficult task, but I cannot find anything on RN.